# HeapFree function - Null parameter?

Tags: visual-c++, null, heap-memory, free

The Windows `HeapFree` function has the following signature:

```
BOOL WINAPI HeapFree(
  _In_ HANDLE hHeap,
  _In_ DWORD  dwFlags,
  _In_ LPVOID lpMem
);
```

In the documentation there is not mention about what is supposed to happen if `hHeap` is null.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366701(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Surely you can just try it yourself?  Come back with a real question when it returns TRUE.

Comment: @HansPassant: The fact it is undocumented could mean that in the current version it does something, and in the next one it may do the opposite. So I *suspect* mine is a real question.

Comment: But what happened when you called it with a NULL value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for [`HeapFree`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366701.aspx) says:

> **hHeap [in]**  A handle to the heap whose memory block is to be freed. This handle is returned by either the `HeapCreate` or `GetProcessHeap` function.

You must pass a valid heap handle.  `NULL` is not a valid heap handle (both `HeapCreate` and `GetProcessHeap` indicate failure by returning `NULL`).  If you do not pass a valid heap handle, the behavior is undefined.